# How to add conent (text) to Add New pages form of admin in WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, pages, shortcode, wp-admin

I am new to WordPress. I have created a  `Shortcode`. Now I want to add description of `Shortcode` to Pages->Add New Page so the user can easily use the `Shortcode` which I have created.

I want that text to be added on plugin activation with `register_activation_hook` and will get removed on deactivation with `register_deactivation_hook`.

Answer (score 0):

The hook to use here is `admin_notices`. However in `register_activation_hook` and `register_deactivation_hook` it shouldn't be used because these function run when plugin activates and deactivates instance.

A workaround it we use `add_option` when plugin activates and `delete_option` when plugin deactivates.

Here is the code. Hopefully you will understand it properly

```
    <?php 
    function my_admin_notice() {
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if($screen->post_type != 'your-post-type-name')
            return;
        if($screen->base != 'post')
            return;
        ?>
        <div class="updated">
            <p><?php _e( 'Updated!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function display_admin_notice(){
        $display_admin_msg = get_option('display_admin_msg');
        if($display_admin_msg == 1){
            add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_init','display_admin_notice');

    function my_plugin_activate() {
         add_option('display_admin_msg',1);
    }
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate' );


    function myplugin_deactivate(){
        delete_option('display_admin_msg');
    }
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivate' );
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where the notice will be displayed?

Comment: Top of every page inside admin panel.

Comment: Actually I want it only on "Add New Page" and "Add New Post" of admin and it should be like a note for page placed below the form.

Comment: I updated the above code. You can check.

Comment: Thanks @karun 
But it is showing like notice on top of the page I want it to be display below the form as label or page content.

Comment: Here are few resources to help you understand more about the hooks and functions
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference